# how to send the form data to my node server... the code am written is,

Tags: javascript

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
 
app.post('/route', function(req,res){
 let inputContent = req.body.textField;
 console.log(inputContent);
});
app.listen(4000);
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <form id="formId">
   <input type="text" id="textFieldId" name="textField">
   <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
  </form>
 <script>
  $("#formId").submit(function (event) {
  $.post('/route', $("#formId").serialize(), function (data) {
  console.log(data) //data is the response from the backend
  });
  event.preventDefault();
  });
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

how to solve it..

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. This is not a tutorial site, so you will have to do the work yourself.

Comment: Did you check the 'console.log(event)'? Is it working ??

Comment: Removed unwanted words

Answer (score 0):

To handle HTTP POST request in Express.js version 4 and above, you need to install middleware module called body-parser.

body-parser extract the entire body portion of an incoming request stream and exposes it on req.body.

The middleware was a part of Express.js earlier but now you have to install it separately.

This body-parser module parses the JSON, buffer, string and URL encoded data submitted using HTTP POST request. Install body-parser using NPM as shown below.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```